# Java - maven cucumber parallel tests - browser opens with blank page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, parallel-processing, cucumber

I have 2 separate feature files. When I run parallel tests using maven command 2 separate browsers show up but first opens with blank page without even url address and nothing happens, however second opens correctly and executes the test successfully. So the first feature file is failed, second is passed.

Hint: when I remove 2 following lines

```
<parallel>classesAndMethods</parallel>
<useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
```

from maven surefire plugin both feature files run one by one and tests are executed successfully (but not in parallel what I want).

```
Feature: test of a webpage one

  @desktop
  Scenario: Test landing page one
    Given Customer clicks something one 
    When Customer clicks something two
    Then Customer clicks something three
```

Second feature file

```
Feature: test of a webpage two

  @desktop
  Scenario: Test landing page two
    Given Customer clicks something one 
    When Customer clicks something two
    Then Customer clicks something three
```

I have in my POM.xml file the following maven-surefire-plugin configuration - is this configuration good or not ? Maybe maven-surefire-plugin configuration is wrong ?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/TestRunner.java</include>
        </includes>
        <parallel>classesAndMethods</parallel>
        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have test runner class

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features",
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/jsonReports/cucumber-report.json",
                "html:target/jsonReports/cucumber-report.html"},
        glue= {"stepDefs"},
      
        )
public class TestRunner {
}
```

Comment: How do you create your web driver. Sounds like you may be assigning it to a static field.

Comment: yes, I am using static webdriver: @Getter
public static WebDriver driver;

public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

Comment: is there a way to get round tis problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724604/how-to-design-a-cucumber-selenium-framework-without-using-static-instances-of-th/67729493#67729493

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541200/is-threadlocal-required-for-automation-framework-that-uses-cucumber-jmeter-and/65541795#65541795

Comment: Not quite your problem, but the solution is comparable: Don't use a static webdriver.

Comment: is there other way to create non static webdriver in page factory pattern than public class LazyWebDriver implements Webdriver, Disposable ? This solution does not look good

Comment: could you help me how to remote static from my framework ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76439006/java-selenium-how-to-convert-static-webdriver-to-non-static-in-page-object-pat