# Java selenium - how to convert static webDriver to non static in page object pattern?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

I want to convert static webDriver to non static webDriver in page factory pattern. Could you tell me how should I modify all classes to make it work ? I want to avoid null pointer exception in sharing webDriver between page objects.

```
public class Page {

@Getter @Setter
public static WebDriver driver;

public Page(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
}
```

This is my step def class:

```
import static utils.Page.driver;

public class LandingPageStepDefs {

    private LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage(driver);
   
    @And("Customer does something")
    public void customerDoesSomething() {
        landingPage.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This is my page object class

```
public class LandingPage extends Page {

    @FindBy(xpath = "this is xpath")
    private WebElement pageWebElement;

}

public LandingPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public void doSomething() {
    pageWebElement.click();
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of factors you have to consider. For example what kind of application are you testing on? Is it a responsive Webapp with lots of variations of layout and dynamically loading elements or is it more like a Website only containing unformatted  lists and the data you´d like to scrape. Depending on those factors it might even be less helpful to convert to page/object based pattern.

Comment: Here is some information to decide whether it could be worth for you: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/encouraged/page_object_models/     https://daniel-delimata.medium.com/is-page-object-model-overrated-4a6777b7a7ed

Comment: I have to use page object pattern, this is normal responsive webapp.